# VBA error 13 run time

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my code for an interactive cart, but i have

> error 13 run time

```
Sub Freeform124_Click()

    Dim NomShape As String

    NomShape = Application.Caller
    For Each Shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        form.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 50, 0)
    Next Shape

End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.Caller` doesn't necessary return a String, try `Dim NomShape As Variant`. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/office/ff193687(v=office.15).aspx for more details

Comment: are you trying to change the color of charts ? Shapes ? what exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you use `for each Shape` loop and then you write `form.fill.forecolor`.
Probably. Plus the `application.caller` parsed to string.

Here is a good way to change the color of all objects, if you make the macro clickable from an object.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Rechteck1_Klicken()

    Dim oCaller         As Object
    Dim shShape         As Shape

    Set oCaller = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    oCaller.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(100, 250, 250)

    For Each shShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shShape.Name <> oCaller.Name Then
            shShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(110, 50, 0)
        End If
    Next shShape

End Sub
```